# Save html values into file through c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, file, createfile

I have this html file. I want to create a text file through c# and save this value on it.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <form onsubmit=""  action="">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" />
      <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Confirm" />
     </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have the html as a file or you have it as a string and want to save it as a file?

Comment: I have it as a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of answers all ready here , but you confusing with word "linking".

In c# you can access any asp.net control in its class file , and also html control by adding runat=server into html control but it have to be in aspx page.

Either switch to aspx to accomplish it in c# or in case of .html file you have to use javascript

You can insert below code in your html file and trigger it through a button

To get HTML of a page into variable

```
var v=$("body").html()
```

And than function to save it into a text file

```
function writeToFile(v)
{
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var fh = fso.OpenTextFile("data.txt", 8, false, 0);
fh.WriteLine(v);
fh.Close();
}
```

Pass var v into writeToFile()

Comment: Thanks, but where I put this call  writeToFile(v) ?

Comment: There must be an html button to export html page in text file  , on click of that button you can call this function .

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is to save html string to a file, you can use:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\words.txt", htmlString);
```

If you already have an HTML file and want to save it as a new file with .txt extension, use un-lucky's answer.

Comment: But how I have to link between c# file and html file?

Comment: what do you mean by "link between"?

Comment: like in ASP.Net we use  CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" , to pass the values

Answer (score 0):

You can make it through [`File.Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx) method, Where you have to pass the path of the `.html` file as source path, the path of the `.txt` as the destination path. then the copy method will create the required text file in the specified path. consider the following code:

```
 File.Copy("index.html","path\\index.txt");
```

Comment: @S.Petrosov: I have checked with the example in the question, is working fine for me. Nothing was removed. If you have option to check means, could you please check and let me know

Comment: But how I have to link between c# file and html file?

Comment: @un-lucky oh sorry it seems  that when I have copied example  "<","/>", and quotes were not copied for some reason, I have found it out just now when checked the html file